# Angular Spring Boot Packaging Issue Whitelabel Error

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I have a Project with Spring Boot as the backend and Angular as the fronted.
The way I package is, I build the angular project and copy the contents into Spring Boot resource folder and in my Spring Boot Controller I return the index.html generated by angular.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    ISupportedLanguagesRepository is;

    @RequestMapping(value={ "/", ""})
    public String getIndex() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

And all the other controllers are REST api calls to the backend. 
All the routes work well when i run the Spring Boot and Angular Project separately.

But when I package them together the routes work only when all the navigations are done through the application. But when I directly try to fetch the url, it gives me this

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.

But it works when i go to this route from the application.

How do I Solve this issue? Even hitting refresh on any page gives the same error.

Comment: please check angular deployment https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: did you try to enable the HashLocationStrategy?

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`

Comment: the error looks as a Spring error and is perhaps due to the fact that when you go tp this URL directly, you skip the server (ajax) calls which were made when you went to this URL from the application, and which initialized the state in services/components and so on. When you go to the URL directly, ir may be that these calls are not made, the state is not initialized, and consequently you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved, as dirk mentioned, by using {useHash: true} in the routes